# I want to uninstall Python3 and just use 2.7

Tags: python, uninstall, dependencies, python3

I typed in this to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3
```

And it gave me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu-extra gir1.2-secret-1 icedtea-netx-common libbonobo2-0
  libbonobo2-common libcpufreq0 libgconf2-4 libgif4 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0
  liborbit2 tzdata-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl apturl-common bluez bluez-alsa
  bluez-gstreamer checkbox checkbox-qt command-not-found
  deja-dup-backend-ubuntuone dh-python firefox flashplugin-installer
  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds friends friends-dispatcher friends-facebook
  friends-twitter gedit gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-datetime gnome-control-center-signon
  gnome-control-center-unity gnome-menus gnome-orca gnome-user-share
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-cpufreq language-selector-common
  language-selector-gnome libfriends0 lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure
  lsb-release nautilus-share onboard onboard-data oneconf openprinting-ppds
  printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch
  printer-driver-pxljr python-commandnotfound python-ubuntuone-client
  python-ubuntuone-control-panel python3 python3-apport python3-apt
  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
  python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-chardet python3-commandnotfound
  python3-crypto python3-dbus python3-debian python3-defer python3-dirspec
  python3-distupgrade python3-feedparser python3-gdbm python3-gi
  python3-gi-cairo python3-httplib2 python3-louis python3-lxml python3-mako
  python3-markupsafe python3-oauthlib python3-oneconf
  python3-piston-mini-client python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report
  python3-pyatspi python3-six python3-software-properties python3-speechd
  python3-uno python3-update-manager python3-xdg python3-xkit rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone
  sessioninstaller software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  system-config-printer-gnome thin-client-config-agent
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-drivers-common
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-standard ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-control-panel
  ubuntuone-control-panel-qt ufw unattended-upgrades unity-lens-friends
  unity-lens-photos unity-scope-audacious unity-scope-calculator
  unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-clementine
  unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks
  unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet
  unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages
  unity-scope-musique unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc
  unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp
  unity-scope-zotero unity-tweak-tool update-manager update-manager-core
  update-notifier update-notifier-common usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk
  webaccounts-extension-common xdiagnose xul-ext-ubufox xul-ext-unity
  xul-ext-webaccounts
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 147 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 162 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

Why does it ask me to uninstall all of that other stuff? Problems from a Linux noob :/

Comment: Why? If you want to use 2.7 for your own code, use `/usr/bin/python`, though you should really be writing new code with python3.

Comment: Is python3 that widely used yet? I got the impression that earlier versions would be the most popular still for a little longer. And since the syntax for 3, even for things like print statements is sometimes incompatible with 2, I feel like I should wait a little while. If not, please convince me otherwise, I love new information! :D

Comment: Yes, it is widely used. That should be pretty obvious from the apt-get remove suggesting other dependencies to be removed.

Comment: It is not used here.  All it does is take up the limited space on my systems and backups.

Comment: @SDsolar Core parts of Ubuntu do require python3. If you wish to remove things and understand what you're doing, then do it. I'm not sure why you made such comments on this nearly 4 year old question.

Comment: Google doesn't notice the age when it puts one of these questions at the top of the list when I search.  Meanwhile, I have decided to leave it be.  TNX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with what is called dependencies.

Those apps depend on "[python3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3)" being installed to function properly.

You can still install any other version of python you want, but will need to specifically call that version at the command-line.

Comment: Makes sense. I could swear that those apps (like rhythmbox, firefox, etc) were all installed prior to my Python3 install though, when I only had the default Python 2.7.5+ pre-installed.

Comment: I have both 2.7 and 3 installed. I know it may not make sense to uninstall 3, it's for curiosity somewhat at this point. I can't remember why I originally wanted to. I guess I thought it was messing something on the OS up haha.

Comment: @virtualxtc That's not exactly true. Rhythmbox depends on python >= 2.7 (but 3.0 does not satisfy that, as the package name is not python).

Comment: @dobey  I think what you meant to say was: "Rhythmbox depends on python >= 2.7 (but 2.7 does not satisfy that, as the package name is not python) - and thanks; I hadn't considered that.

Comment: @virtualxtc No, I meant what I said. `python` is only available as python 2.x. The python 3.x package is `python3`. Rhythmbox in <= 13.10 cannot be installed without python 2.7 (in the default archive packages).

Comment: Ok, so now I'm confused as to whether UnworthyToast's question was answered.  If Rhythmbox depends on "python" >= 2.7, why using apt to remove "python3" cause it to also remove Rhythmbox?  UnworthyToast - Did you have python 2.7 installed when you ran the "apt-get remove python3" command?

Comment: I know why I want to remove it - My Raspbian systems run from 32GB SD cards.  My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS systems run on 160 GB SSD drives.   It takes up a lot of space on the primary drives and in every backup.  And I never use it on purpose.

Comment: @dobey @SDsolar According to the [dependency list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/rhythmbox)  `rhythmbox` depends on `python3` not `python`

Comment: @virtualxtc Yes. And in the nearly 4 years since the previous commentary on this question, many packaging bugs have likely been resolved, and dependencies have further changed.