# Huge Python Problem

Tags: python, python3

Preamble: I tried looking up a solution and nothing worked for me.

First, when I run the following command

```
$ sudo python --version
Python 2.7.5+
```

Similarly for python2 and 3

```
$ sudo python2 --version
Python 2.7.5+
$ sudo python3 --version
Python 2.7.5+
```

I get the same exact thing

When I try to, for example, install firefox

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

I get the problem this person is having

[I want to uninstall Python3 and just use 2.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390440/i-want-to-uninstall-python3-and-just-use-2-7)

First, the solution did not work for me. Rather, I am not exactly sure what this person is saying in how you specify.

Two, I can't reinstall python3

---

Update

I reinstalled python 3.4.3 from source and when I check the version of python3 I still get python 2.7.5+.

---

Reply to Michael Lindman

```
root@bl-bc-120431:/home/lab/Desktop/Python-3.4.3# ls -al /usr/bin/ |grep python
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          26 Feb  4  2014 dh_pypy -> ../share/dh-python/dh_pypy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        1056 Sep 19  2013 dh_python2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          29 Feb  4  2014 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root          94 Feb 27  2014 idle-python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          23 Feb 27  2014 pdb2.7 -> ../lib/python2.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          23 Feb 27  2014 pdb3.3 -> ../lib/python3.3/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          31 Feb  4  2014 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          26 Feb  4  2014 pybuild -> ../share/dh-python/pybuild
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           9 Sep 19  2013 python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           9 Sep 19  2013 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     3336168 Feb 27  2014 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          33 Feb 27  2014 python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         178 Dec 14  2011 python2.7-pyrexc
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          16 Sep 19  2013 python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          18 Mar 25 13:57 python3 -> /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     3928976 Feb 27  2014 python3.3m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          10 Feb  4  2014 python3m -> python3.3m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          16 Sep 19  2013 python-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          29 Sep 19  2013 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        2916 Feb 27  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        2885 Feb 27  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-dbg-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          33 Sep 19  2013 x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
```

---

Second Reply to Michael Lindman

```
root@bl-bc-120431:/home/lab/Desktop/Python-3.4.3# apt-get install --reinstall python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apparmor-easyprof apt-clone archdetect-deb bogl-bterm dpkg-repack libdebconfclient0
  libdebian-installer4 python-xkit python3-icu python3-pam rdate sbsigntool
  screen-resolution-extra ubiquity ubiquity-casper ubiquity-frontend-debconf
  ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
57 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,166 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 313616 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace python3 3.3.2-14ubuntu1 (using .../python3_3.3.2-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb)     ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.3.2-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: py3compile: not     found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.3.2-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking, can you clarify? Also it is just a thought but if running `python3 --version` outputs `Python 2.7.5+` then it might be a problem with Symbolic links. Could you please run `ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep python` and add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know where to post it so I will post it under Michael Lindman in the original post.

Comment: As I thought, python3 is symlinked to `/usr/bin/python2.7` and is why running python3 returns `Python 2.7.5+`.

Comment: Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: You could try removing the symlink with `sudo rm /usr/bin/python3` and reinstalling python3 with `sudo apt-get install --reinstalled python3` but I'm not entirely sure if it will work or not.

Comment: Alright, I may have found out a way to fix it but it is a little weird to say the least. I can replicate your error if I remove my python3 but if I symlink it to `python3m` with the command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3m /usr/bin/python3` and if I run `apt-get install --reinstalled python3` it will reinstall python3 without any problems, after that remove python3 again with `sudo rm /usr/bin/python3` and symlink it to python3.4 with `ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Unfortunately Something else happened to the point where the terminal is gone and the sidebar is gone. We are having IT team here reinstall the system. I wish I could have tried your solution. Unless you are familiar with why my terminal disappeared along with the sidebar. All that is visible are the folders. Anyway, thank you.